# Can't store values on a struct defined in a library

Tags: c

**In main:**

```
#include stdio.h

#include stdlib.h

#include string.h

#include dictionary.h


int main( int argc, char ** argv ){

  dictionary_t dictionary = NULL;
  dictionary->entries = 1;
  return 0;
}
```

**//In header**

```
#ifndef DICTIONARY_H

#define DICTIONARY_H

struct dictionary_s{

  char * name;
  llist_t content;
  int entries;    
};
typedef struct dictionary_s* dictionary_t;

#endif
```

//It compiles but shows Segmentation Fault (Core dump) in the console screen.
I have tried almost everything  I can think of and checked several posts, but I've been unable to solve this problem.

Comment: You are accessing a NULL pointer. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: you need to assign dictionary to the value of an address that is accessible to your program.  Either create something on the stack and use the & "address of" operator, or malloc memory on the heap.  You should start by trying to malloc memory on the heap, but you are in for what looks like a steep learning curve so stick with it!

Comment: Maybe its not that steep of a learning curve :)

Comment: `#include stdio.h` should not compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In main:

#include stdio.h

#include stdlib.h

#include string.h

#include dictionary.h


int main( int argc, char ** argv ){

  //dictionary_t dictionary = NULL;//This was your old line that leads to a null pointer voilation..
  dictionary_t dictionary = (dictionary_t *) malloc(sizeof(dictionary_t));
  if( NULL == dictionary){
    //malloc failed, what do you wanna do now?
    printf("Malloc failed\n");
    //exit(-1);
    while(1){} //just spin forever so you can see the error i suppose?
  }
  dictionary->entries = 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Here is a malloc example, the stack example is similar but different.
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdlib.h/malloc